# Google Maps API Drawing Library - Is there any way to update shape coordinates as you are dragging one point?

Tags: javascript, api, maps, listener

When dragging a point - not the whole shape - in the Google Maps drawing library, is there a way to check for an event and update the coordinates as the drag is happening?